# How do I perform bitwise operations on binary values in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

The SQLAlchemy documentation suggests that a program can access sql's bitwise operators by simply using the `op` function, like `expression.op('&')(0x04)`. However, I get anomalous results when I use it on binary values:

```
with Session(engine) as sess:
     stmt = select(table.c.myvarbinary.op('&')(myBytes))
     result = sess.execute(stmt).fetchone()
     print(x[0])
```

prints `b''`

If I bypass SQLAlchemy's api, the operator works correctly:

```
with Session(engine) as sess:
     stmt = text(f'SELECT myvarbinary & {myBytes.hex()} FROM table;')
     result = sess.execute(stmt).fetchone()
     print(x[0])
```

prints `b'[expected result]'`

I'm blocked on what might be the reason for this. The database I'm connected to uses MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my database did not interpret the incoming bytes properly as a bytestring; I was able to fix the issue by explicitly adding a CAST to the statement.

`stmt = select(table.c.myvarbinary.op('&')(cast(myBytes, types.LargeBinary))`